# Added Web Service reference getting error missing namespace

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, compiler-errors

In `Visual Studio` I just added a web service reference to my `Asp.net` website, but when i try to use web service instance in code it says `missing type , namespace`. The weird thing is when i change target framework from 3.5 to 4 this error goes away. any ideas whats happening?

Comment: The problem may be that you're using a web site instead of a web application project. They cause weird things like this, which is one reason I don't use them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders so if i open the website using .sln file that should solve it?

Comment: No. That's still a web site. You may want to right-click and use Convert to Web Application Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better to do wsdl.exe your web service then include its proxy class in your client code

> > C:\Windows\system32>wsdl.exe /out:C:\MyServiceProxy.cs "https://whatever.com/Myservice.asmx?
> >     WSDL"
> >     
> > Or you can:
> >     Right click project in solution explorer > Add Reference > .Net Tab > System.Web.Extension add reference and should be all set

Answer (score -2):

What version are you working in originally? There's probably just a versioning incompatibility. Any reason you can't just use .NET 4?

Comment: its a big project i can't change target framework from 3.5 to 4 unless a major requirement comes up